# Three State CheckBox Binding Self Default Value

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

How can I default a three state checkbox to null when the IsChecked binding is set?  FallbackValue="{x:Null}" does not seem to work?  I'm trying to get the checkbox to default to null instead of false.

```
<CheckBox IsThreeState="True">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                 Path="IsChecked"
                 FallbackValue="{x:Null}"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <Validators:StandardValidators />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
```

Update 1:
To explicitly trigger the validation I use:

```
    private void SaveChanges()
    {
         if (!this.ValidateForm(this.GridContainingCheckboxes))
         {
              return;
         {

         var myObject = new CustomObject();
         myObject.InspectedElement = myCheckbox.IsChecked;

         // Save Stuff Here
    }

    private bool ValidateForm(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        var result = true;

        foreach (var checkBox in this.ChildrenOfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            var bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(checkBox, ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty);

            if (bindingExpression != null)
            {
                bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
            }
        }

        if (!this.IsValid(obj))
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private bool IsValid(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return !Validation.GetHasError(obj) && LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj).OfType<DependencyObject>().All(child => this.IsValid(child));
    }
```

Update 2:

```
public class StandardValidators : ValidationRule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="StandardValidators"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public StandardValidators()
    {
        this.AllowNull = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets ErrorMessage.
    /// </summary>
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether AllowNull.
    /// </summary>
    public bool AllowNull { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether IsBoolean.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsBoolean { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main validator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">
    /// The value.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="cultureInfo">
    /// The culture info.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The validation result.
    /// </returns>
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var result = new ValidationResult(true, null);

        if (!this.AllowNull)
        {
            if (this.IsBoolean && (value as bool?) == null)
            {
                this.ErrorMessage = "Cannot Be Null";
                return new ValidationResult(false, this.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: So nothing is ever bound to the CheckBox you just want it to show null as default?, what does this checkbox do if its not bound to anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value you can set in `EventTrigger` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chb" IsThreeState="True">
...
    <CheckBox.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="chb"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </CheckBox.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

**Edit:**

You can use *System.Windows.Interactivity* assembly to set default value.

Create helper class to set properties:

```
public class SetterAction : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
    public SetterAction()
    {
        Setters = new List<Setter>();
    }

    public List<Setter> Setters { get; set; }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        foreach (var item in Setters)
        {
            AssociatedObject.SetValue(item.Property, item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML code:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="InspectOverallUnitToggleButton" IsThreeState="True">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                 Path="IsChecked"
                 FallbackValue="{x:Null}"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <Validators:StandardValidators IsBoolean="True"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>              
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:EventTrigger.Actions>
                <local:SetterAction>
                    <local:SetterAction.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </local:SetterAction.Setters>
                </local:SetterAction>
            </i:EventTrigger.Actions>
        </i:EventTrigger>                  
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

Where `i` is:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

*System.Windows.Interactivity.dll* assembly you can find in Microsoft Expression Blend 3 SDK ([link)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22829).

Comment: This prevent's the user from being able to edit the value of the CheckBox.

Comment: @BitOriented check my answer again :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason `FallbackValue` is not working is because the `CheckBoxes` `IsChecked` has a valid value (false) so it will use that instead of the `FallbackValue`.

Based on the example you attached using `OverrideMetadata` seems to work fine in your solution, below is the code I used.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CheckBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((bool?)null));
    InitializeComponent();

    // if you want to show validation errors on load.
    Loaded += (s, e) => this.ValidateForm(this.MainGrid);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to let the UpdateSource() fire and trigger the validation rules.

Comment: what are you tring to do? if the checkbox is not bound to anything what are you validating.

Comment: That the user has interacted with the checkbox, and the assigned value is either true or false, but not null. It needs to be null by default, because for an inspection the user must make a selection.

Comment: Here is a link to a test project.  The validation (red highlight is what I'm wanting as well as the early out.)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8sxq42s0v7d7bz/ToggleButtonTest.zip

Comment: You could just override the metadata of IsChecked to display as null, added example above

Comment: I downloaded your sample and have posted an edit to my answer with a solution that works.